# Processing dataset tables result dynamically

Tags: c#, sql

I have a query regarding processing the results of the dataset dynamically.

So I have a generic function that gets the data from the database and returns the dataset.
As the function which generates the database query is dynamic and could generate one or more table queries based on business logic.
I can fire the query for each table one by one and parse the data, However, I want to fire all the queries at once and parse the data.
I can't make a switch based on a table index as it might get shifted based on the generated query.
Is there any better way to achieve this.

Comment: I usually use a SQL DataAdapter which does most of the work and will return a single datatable where the  command text contains joins.  Once you have a single datatable you can  use dt.Columns to get a names of the columns in the table.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not using joins here. My statement could have select clause for one or more tables separated by semi colon. So once i fire the query i dont know how many tables would be there in dataset.Also in dataset table names are like table0,table1 where i can't recognize that which relates to which table.

Comment: The query I would add "as Table name" so you know the tables that are being returned.

Comment: @jdweng You mean if my query has Select * from person AS Person1 than i would get table name as Person1 in dataset rather than table0?

Comment: I think it will.  I know when I use AS and specify a different name for a column from the database the datatable gets the AS instead of the database name.  Never tried with table name but I believe it is the same as a column.